# Using EMC DAEs standalone

Tags: fiber, emc, hba

I've got a number of EMC DAEs filled with drives, for free. I'd love to use them, as they total to around 30TB, with possibly more available from the same recycling facility.

As of right now I can run individual drives just fine, after formatting them to a 512 byte sector size. I'd like to be able to use them in the racks, however. They have two HSSDC2 connectors, for "PRImary" (to go to an HBA or the previous rack), and "EXPansion" (to daisy-chain to the next rack. I also have a number of HBAs with LC connectors, and LC cable, which I'd like to use as opposed to buying other cables or HBAs.

What is the best way to go about this? There are no HSSDC2 to LC adapters that I can find, and various solutions cost between $100 and $500 to do this conversion. There doesn't seem to be any truly professional company that sells products for this.

Edit: I used a Brocade fibre switch to solve this. For $40, I can do this exactly, and increase total bandwidth available, since I'm not longer daisy-chaining the HD racks.

Comment: Welcome to [sf]. This is not a forum. Please post answers in the Answer section, not in the Question.

Comment: Duly noted. I *am* fairly new to Stack Exchange in general. Thank you.